# Do I need a new query object for each MySQL statement?

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm trying to compile several MySQL statements and execute them in the same request, but I keep getting a MySQL syntax error:

```
local.sql = "";
for (local.i in this.hitArray)
{
    local.sql &= "UPDATE posts SET viewCount = posts.viewCount + 1 WHERE posts.id = #local.i.postId#;";
}
local.service.setSQL(local.sql);
```

Raw SQL dump (local.sql var):

`UPDATE posts SET viewCount = posts.viewCount + 1 WHERE posts.id = 95;UPDATE posts SET viewCount = posts.viewCount + 1 WHERE posts.id = 95;UPDATE posts SET viewCount = posts.viewCount + 1 WHERE posts.id = 95;`

It appears the query is chocking right at the end of the first statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL disables multiple statements by default to prevent sql injection. You must add the [allowMultiQueries](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1209-Turning-On-Multiple-Statements-In-ColdFusion-8-MySQL-4-5-Datasource.htm) flag to your connection string to enable them.

Note: Obviously if you enable multiple statements, it is very important all of your queries use cfqueryparam or addParam because you are now at risk for sql injection.

Comment: thank you. I enabled this, and restarted all my services. I still get an SQL error. I think there needs to be a blank line between the statements, and #chr(13)# doesn't seem to be doing the trick... the error is occurring right at the end of the first statement.

Comment: Not a new line, but a semi-colon ie ";".

Comment: Did you try adding a semi-colon to separate the statements?

Comment: Yes, this has got to be a ColdFusion issue. I dumped the raw SQL and tried it in my console. It worked perfectly... :/

Comment: Even with semi-colons at the end of each statement? Can you update your question to include the raw SQL and the full error message?

Comment: @Leigh, I just posted the updates... yes, it's failing with the semi-colon, strange... I tried with and without using a param to no difference.

Comment: @Mohamad - Something is off, because that exact code works fine for me. Did you double check the dsn settings, db version, restarting, etcetera?

Comment: I'm going to restart my computer... I restarted services, tested the connection, etc... I'll check back in a few minutes. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: The error is still there. Can I ask you what version of CF are you running? My config is `AFC 9,0,1,274733`; `MySQL 5.1.46`; `Java 1.6.0_17`

Comment: Same except for MySQL 5.1.42. Which driver type does your DSN use, "MySQL4/5" or "Other"? Are you sure there is nothing else going on that we cannot see? If you a hard coded cfquery with two statements `SELECT @@version as v;SELECT @@version as v;` does it work? If yes, the problem is your other code.

Comment: @Leigh, it's using 'MySQL 4/5' ... I tried that already, and I got the same error.

Comment: I also added a new test, seperately, another function, static, with a custom loop. I set the counter to 1, it works, set it to two, it blows up. Either my AFC or MySQL are buggered.

Comment: @Mohamad let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2243/discussion-between-leigh-and-mohamad)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The post should say `allowMultiQueries`. Typo fixed.